# Sacar texto de multiples Inputs kivy

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

Dispongo del siguiente ejemplo en python kyvi:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.recycleview import RecycleView
from kivy.uix.recycleview.views import RecycleDataViewBehavior
import json

#esta funcion nos devolvera el valor del json
def sacar_nombres():
    with open('data/centros.json') as f:
        places = json.load(f)
    return places

items = sacar_nombres()


class Fila(GridLayout):
    id_fila = ObjectProperty()
    text_input = ObjectProperty()
    text_label = ObjectProperty()


class Marco(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Marco,self).__init__()
        self.crearBotones()

    def sacar_ids(self):
        print('pulsado')
        print(self.ids)

    def crearBotones(self):
        for item in items:
            f = Fila()
            f.id_fila = item['centro']
            f.text_input = item['nombre']
            f.text_label = str(item['centro'])
            self.add_widget(f)

class Botones(BoxLayout):
    pass
KV = '''


<Fila>:
    cols: 2
    id_fila: ''
    text_input: ''
    text_label: ''
    id: root.id_fila
    TextInput:
        id: root.id_fila
        text: root.text_input
    Label:
        id: id_labelid
        text: root.text_label
<Marco>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'horizontal'
        size_hint_y: None
        height: 50
        Button:
            text:'1'
            on_press: 
                root.sacar_ids()
        Button:
            text:'2'


'''


class Test(App):
    def build(self):
        Builder.load_string(KV)
        return Marco()


Test().run()
```

He intentado sacar mediante los ids los valores de los inputs pero el array de ids se encuentra vacio. No sé cómo podría acceder a cada elemento y sacar de él la informacíon de text de cada input al pulsar uno de los botones. He probado a meter los botones como BoxLayout, antes eran otra clase, pero sigue sin coger los Id. No entiendo bien como hacer referencia a los elementos que ya se han construido en kivy, ni he encontrado información clara al respecto. Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El diccionario `ids` solo almacena las ids de los widgets creados en el .kv y que se les asignó una.

Para los widgets generados en el código debes usar el atributo `children` que es una `ListProperty`, por ejemplo:

```
from kivy.properties import StringProperty

# ...

class Fila(GridLayout):
    text_input = StringProperty()
    text_label = StringProperty()


class Marco(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.crear_filas()

    def sacar_ids(self):
        for child in self.children:
            if isinstance(child, Fila):
                print(child)
                print(f"    Text label:{child.text_label}")
                print(f"    Text input:{child.text_input}")

    def crear_filas(self):
        for item in items:
            f = Fila()
            f.text_input = item['nombre']
            f.text_label = str(item['centro'])
            self.add_widget(f)
```

Otra posibilidad es que te crees un atributo para almacenar en específico las filas, administrando de forma adecuada la adición o eliminación de nuevas filas:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.properties import StringProperty, DictProperty
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.recycleview import RecycleView
from kivy.uix.recycleview.views import RecycleDataViewBehavior
import json


JSON_PATH = 'data/centros.json'

KV = '''


<Fila>:
    cols: 2
    centro: ''
    nombre: text_input.text

    TextInput:
        id: text_input
        text: root.nombre
    Label:
        text: root.centro

<Marco>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'horizontal'
        size_hint_y: None
        height: 50
        Button:
            text:'Obtener Datos'
            on_press:
                root.obtener_datos()
        Button:
            text:''
'''


class Fila(GridLayout):
    centro = StringProperty()
    nombre = StringProperty()

    def __init__(self, centro, nombre, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.centro = centro
        self.nombre = nombre


class Marco(BoxLayout):
    filas = DictProperty()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.cargar_datos()

    def agregar_fila(self, centro, nombre):
        fila = Fila(centro, nombre)
        self.add_widget(fila)
        self.filas[centro] = fila

    def eliminar_fila(self, centro):
        fila = self.filas.get(centro)
        if fila is not None:
            self.remove_widget(fila)
            del self.filas[centro]

    def obtener_datos(self):
        data = [{"centro": row.centro,
                  "nombre": row.nombre}
                for id_, row in self.filas.items()]
        print(data)
        return data

    def cargar_datos(self):
        with open(JSON_PATH) as f:
            places = json.load(f)
        for place in places:
            self.agregar_fila(str(place['centro']), place['nombre'])


class Test(App):
    def build(self):
        Builder.load_string(KV)
        return Marco()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Test().run()
```